# Can compound relative pronoun be omitted?

Tags: relative-pronouns

The sentence "we can do to keep them down is great", which I used the grammar webpage to check. The grammar webpage is showing it is correct. But I think the more correct sentence would be "whatever we can do to keep them down is great".  It is means "whatever" can be omitted, right?

Comment: Whatever the webpage says, the sentence does not make sense. It needs a subject such as _whatever_ or _anything_.

Comment: @Kate Bunting. thank you for replying. 
let me modify this sentence
1.  "we concern the cost, whatever we can do to keep them down is great." 
2.  "we concern the cost, we can do to keep them down is great."
which one is correct? thank you again.

Comment: _Cost_ is singular, so it should be _keep it down_ (or use _costs_ instead). You still need a subject for the main clause. We're not supposed to do proofreading, but I'll just mention that the first part needs to be _Concerning the cost(s)_, or _As concerns the cost(s)_.

Answer (score 1):

"Whatever" is necessary, because the sentence requires an object of "can do."